# transforming an iterative function to recursive in java

Tags: java

i want to transform this function to recursive form could anyone help me thx
that function is to solve this stuff

```
X=1+(1+2)*2+(1+2+3)*2^2+(1+2+3+4)*2^3+ . . . +(1+2+3+4+. . . +n)*2^(n-1)
```

```
public static int calcX(int n) {
        int x=1;
        int tmp;
        for(int i = 1 ; i <= n-1;i++) {
            tmp=0;
            for(int j = 1 ; j <= i + 1;j++) {
                tmp+=j;
            }
            x+=tmp*Math.pow(2, i);
        }
        return x;
    }
```

my attempt im new to recursive stuff

```
public static int calcXrecu(int n,int tmp,int i,int j) {
        int x=1;
        if(i <= n-1) {
            if(j <= i) {
                calcXrecu(n,tmp+j,i,j+1);
            }
            else {
                x = (int) (tmp*Math.pow(2, i));
            }
        }
        else {
            x=1;
        }
            return x;
    }
```

Comment: Also, this looks like a "please write code for me request", and this risks the question being closed. Please show your attempt and use it to help you ask a better and more specific question.

Comment: i didnt put my attempt because it was crap :(

Comment: Crap is better than nothing.

Comment: Try using ```public static int calcXrecu(int n)``` as the method signature itself and compute the value of ```sum(n) * 2^(n-1) + calcXrecu(n-1)```. Make sure you dont forget a base case for the recursive calls or you risk infinite recursion.

Comment: the problem is how to calc the sum(n) because i used the nested loop to calculate it

Comment: Try breaking it into pieces.  First concentrate on doing `repetitive sums of x` using recursion.  Print out the values that you get as they happen.  Then try and add the additional recursive call(s) to get the previous `value * times the power of 2`.

Comment: You could create another recursive function specifically for the sum portion if you want full recursion, or you could just have the sum be iterative.

Comment: @TreyGraham oh so its impossible to have 1 recursive function for both loops ?

Comment: I'm not gonna say it's impossible without having tried to figure it out. But I dont know of a way off the top of my head without delving into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sequence of sums which themselves are sums.
The `n`th term can be derived from the `(n-1)`th term like this:

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + (1+2+3+....+n) * 2^(n-1)  [1]
```

and this is the recursive formula because it produces each term via the previous term.
Now you need another formula (high school math) for the sum of `1+2+3+....+n`:

```
1+2+3+....+n = n * (n + 1) / 2  [2]
```

Now use `[2]` in `[1]`:

```
a(n) = a(n-1) + n * (n + 1) * 2^(n-2)  [3]
```

so you have a formula with which you can derive each term from the previous term and this is all you need for your recursive method:

```
public static int calcXrecu(int n) {
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return calcXrecu(n - 1) + n * (n + 1) * (int) Math.pow(2, n - 2);
}
```

This line:

```
if (n == 1) return 1;
```

is the exit point of the recursion.
Note that `Math.pow(2, n - 2)` needs to be converted to `int` because it returns `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @forpas answer, I also want to provide a solution using [corecursion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/144274/whats-the-difference-between-recursion-and-corecursion) by utilizing `Stream.iterate`. This is obviously not a recursive solution, but I think it is good to know alternatives as well. Note that I use a Pair to represent the tuple of (index, value).

```
public static int calcXcorecu(final int n) {
    return Stream.iterate(
            Pair.of(1, 1), p -> {
                final int index = p.getLeft();
                final int prev = p.getRight();
                final int next = prev + index * (index + 1) * (int) Math.pow(2, index - 2);
                return Pair.of(index + 1, next);
            })
            // only need the n-th element
            .skip(n)
            .limit(1)
            .map(Pair::getRight)
            .findFirst()
            .get();
}
```